# my application that it crashes when I try to use the adapter

Tags: android

**my code**

**I have a UserAdapter, and a Search Fragment and the user_item and user class. The problem is, the three Click Listeners to open the "Search Fragment "  the app crashe!! and close.

i hope so i give u good explanation for the problem
and thanks for the help in advance

**

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private UserAdapter userAdapter;
    private List<User> userList;

    EditText search_bar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        search_bar = view.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);

        userList = new ArrayList<>();
        userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), userList, true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);

        readUsers();
        search_bar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                searchUsers(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void searchUsers(String s){
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").orderByChild("username")
                .startAt(s)
                .endAt(s+"\uf8ff");

        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                userList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    userList.add(user);
                }

                userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void readUsers() {

        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (search_bar.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    userList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                        userList.add(user);

                    }

                    userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

** my code class Use**

```
public class User {
    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String fullname;
    private String imageurl;
    private String bio;

    public User(String id, String username, String fullname, String imageurl, String bio) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.imageurl = imageurl;
        this.bio = bio;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFullname() {
        return fullname;
    }

    public void setFullname(String fullname) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

    public String getImageurl() {
        return imageurl;
    }

    public void setImageurl(String imageurl) {
        this.imageurl = imageurl;
    }

    public String getBio() {
        return bio;
    }

    public void setBio(String bio) {
        this.bio = bio;
    }
}
```

**my code UserAdapter**

```
public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<User> mUsers;
    private boolean isFragment;

    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

    public UserAdapter(Context context, List<User> users, boolean isFragment){
        mContext = context;
        mUsers = users;
        this.isFragment = isFragment;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserAdapter.ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.user_item, parent, false);
        return new UserAdapter.ImageViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final UserAdapter.ImageViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        final User user = mUsers.get(position);

        holder.btn_follow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        isFollowing(user.getId(), holder.btn_follow);

        holder.username.setText(user.getUsername());
        holder.fullname.setText(user.getFullname());
        Glide.with(mContext).load(user.getImageurl()).into(holder.image_profile);

        if (user.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
            holder.btn_follow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (isFragment) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putString("profileid", user.getId());
                    editor.apply();

                    ((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            new ProfileFragment()).commit();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Main2Activity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("publisherid", user.getId());
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

        holder.btn_follow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (holder.btn_follow.getText().toString().equals("follow")) {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                            .child("following").child(user.getId()).setValue(true);
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(user.getId())
                            .child("followers").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);

                    addNotification(user.getId());
                } else {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                            .child("following").child(user.getId()).removeValue();
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(user.getId())
                            .child("followers").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
                }
            }

        });
    }

    private void addNotification(String userid){
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(userid);

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("userid", firebaseUser.getUid());
        hashMap.put("text", "started following you");
        hashMap.put("postid", "");
        hashMap.put("ispost", false);

        reference.push().setValue(hashMap);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUsers.size();
    }

    public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView username;
        public TextView fullname;
        public CircleImageView image_profile;
        public Button btn_follow;

        public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            fullname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fullname);
            image_profile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
            btn_follow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_follow);
        }
    }

    private void isFollowing(final String userid, final Button button){

        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("Follow").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("following");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child(userid).exists()){
                    button.setText("following");
                } else{
                    button.setText("follow");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

** user_item**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/image_profile"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_profile"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:text="username"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fullname"
            android:text="full_name"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:id="@+id/btn_follow"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

stack trace

```
     E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: commenting, PID: 24881
    java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        at commenting.Fragment.SearchFragment.onCreateView(SearchFragment.java:47)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24881 SIG: 9
```

> Fragment.SearchFragment

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragment.SearchFragment">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_search_light"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/search_bar"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="search_bar"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:inputType="text"/>


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bar"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It's very difficult to debug a crash without a stack trace.  See [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](/q/23353173) for Android-specific advice, and [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](/q/3988788) for advice on what to do once you have the stack trace.  If you still need help, edit your question to include the **complete stack trace**, as well as **which line of your code** the stack trace points to.

Comment: E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.                                              E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!

Comment: That's not a stack trace.  Also, edit the stack trace and/or logs into the question, don't put it in comments.

Comment: As @RyanM said, replace the last part of code with the error.

Comment: Include your `fragment_search.xml`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your search fragment layout doesn't have the `RecyclerView` component and the button on that layout has the `recycler_view` id which you try to use to inflate your `RecyclerView`. That's why you're getting this exception.

Add a `RecyclerView` to your layout and set its id to `recycler_view` so that you can grab the RV in your code.

Comment: Can you explain more؟؟؟؟